# Page redirects to homepage after data insertion from form in database

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I don't know why my page redirects to my homepage after submission of data to database from form. The data is submitted succesfully but rather going to submit page it goes to my homepage i.e www.xxxx.com

important details changed to XXX

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXX_officetest";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

// Escape user inputs for security
$cx_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputname']);
$cx_email = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputemail']);
$cx_phone = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputphone']);
$cx_key=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputkey']);
$cx_location=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputlocation']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `xxxxx`.`cux_details` (`cx_name`, `cx_email`, `cx_phone`, `cx_key`, `cx_location`)
VALUES ('$cx_name', '$cx_email', '$cx_phone' ,'$cx_key' ,'$cx_location')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header('Location: http://www.xxxxx.com/submit.html'); //redirect
exit();
}
else{
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/submit.html'); //redirect
exit();
}


mysql_free_result($result);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'Off-topic': change to PDO or MYSQLI_* if you can, as mysql_* is deprecated..

Comment: You need to provide more information for this.  For one, seeing the form would be very helpful.  Also I'm pretty sure your `mysql_free_result` will never be hit due to the redirect above it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the PHP code before outputting any HTML, so your code will be:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXX_officetest";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

// Escape user inputs for security
$cx_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputname']);
$cx_email = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputemail']);
$cx_phone = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputphone']);
$cx_key=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputkey']);
$cx_location=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cxinputlocation']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `xxxxx`.`cux_details` (`cx_name`, `cx_email`, `cx_phone`, `cx_key`, `cx_location`)
VALUES ('$cx_name', '$cx_email', '$cx_phone' ,'$cx_key' ,'$cx_location')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header('Location: http://www.xxxxx.com/submit.html'); //redirect
//exit();
}
else{
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/submit.html'); //redirect
exit();
}


mysql_free_result($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

Content goes here...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the data does get inserted to database but it redirects to my homepage not my submit page.

Comment: no it doesnot.it just redirect to my homepage.Even if i don't put the header lines instead just  echo "success" or "not success",on that as well it redirects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form class="form-horizontal cxform" action="http://www.xxxxxx.com/cx_mail_send.php" method="post">


<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" id="cxinputname" name="cxinputname">
<input required="required" type="email" class="form-control" id="cxinputemail" name="cxinputemail">
<input required="required" type="tel" class="form-control" id="cxinputphone" maxlength="10" name="cxinputphone">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" id="cxinputkey" name="cxinputkey" maxlength="30">
<select class="form-control" name="cxinputlocation">
                        <option value="">Choose Country</option>

<button type="submit" class="btn" id="cxsubmit" value="Submit">Get Started</button>

</form>
```

The option value has lot of value so didnt post.This is my form which call my  cx_mail_send.php.Hope it helps